# JPA/hibernate - Cascade removing from db

Tags: hibernate, jpa, cascade

Hi i have situation like this:

Entity TAG with 2 fields ManyToMany which holds 2 sets of objects (Obj1, Obj2). When i deleting Obj1 i want to delete all info contained in Obj1 set in TAG entity. Can you tell me how to do this?

---

```
@Entity(name = "tag")
public class Tag {

    .....

@ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
private Set<Checkpoint> checkpoints;

    ......
}

@Entity(name = "checkpoint")
public class Checkpoint implements Serializable {

            ......

}
```

There is no reference to tags in checkpoint. And if i set Cascade to ManyToMany then when i remove tag then all user with this tag are removed. What i want is to delete row in tag_checkpoint table when checkpoint is deleted. Should i do it by myself or there is good way to do this??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just removed object from db by myself.

Answer (score 0):

If ManyToMany does cascade deletion, then setting cascade=CascadeType.ALL in your @ManyToMany annotation should work.  If not, then you may want to consider separating into multiple uses of @OneToMany (if possible), with CascadeType.ALL.